# cURL issue using laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

when I use curl to get the content of an html page, I got a wired content which look like a script. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code, and what is this wired content ?

There is my controller :

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://twitter.com',
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);
dd($data);
curl_close($curl);
```

And there is what it's look like in the
[console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP4ie.png)

Thank you for all of your answers.

Comment: `dd()` is `dump and die`, which halts all execution below it. If you want to see the data returned in `$data`, consider using `\Log::info($data);`. That being said, it may error if `$data` is something un-loggable, like a `stdClass Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `dd()` to print the `$data` variable,

Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see the exact response returned by curl.

Its the `dd` that adds extra JS to the output

Here is a better code to do this :

```
$url="https://twitter.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I just tried with `print_r`, but it doesn't print the html content of the web page

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer to add user agent and other curl options, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks for your help, now it works !

At the first try it didn't, but then I just deleted those two lines :
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);` and `$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';`
 and know everything is okay.